# How to remove and back up the sealed tsfile data of Apache IoTDB while not stopping the system from running?

Tags: file, apache-iotdb, iotdb

For Apache IoTDB version 0.13, I want to back up the historical data stored. I already close all the merge progress, and is it possible to directly remove the sealed tsfile when not to stop the service of the IoTDB system? If this kind of process can only be achieved when the system stops running, what other ways can I choose to do this data transfer?

Answer (score 0):

When Apache IoTDB is still operating, it is not possible to move all tsfiles, although they are sealed. You can do this after you shutdown IoTDB. Or if you want to do backup without stopping IoTDB, you can do this by setting ttl. The process may be like this: 1. Stop all merging tasks. 2. Back up all sealed tsfiles during operation. 3. Set time range of ttl, for example, half a year. 4. Enable merging tasks.